# `float` vs `double` in casual single computations?

Tags: floating-point

I see some people write code where casual uses of something that needs floating point is declared to use a `float` type (in C/C++).  This isn't a huge matrix where space matters, or trying to fit more into SIMD, or anything like that.  Little things like scaling a value by a percentage, or finding a ratio between quantities.

I'd always used `double` and considered `float` to be only for when space really mattered.  I recall the days when desktop CPUs did not have floating point hardware and there might be something said about performance of the software library, but with the first ’287 co-processor the native precision was 80 bits anyway and `float` was just for the long-term storage of values in RAM or in files, and didn't affect computation speed one iota.

**Today, is there any reason to use `float` instead of `double` in such habitual manner?**  Situation 1:  specific to PC/Mac hardware;  Situation 2:  portable code which may be on desktops and mobile devices like phones too.

Should I educate my team the way I remember: *Hey, you know, `float` is a half sized thing and `double` is normal.* or is there some trade off or reason why C++ programmers would use `float` everywhere and seemingly (to my POV) not know that `double` existed?

My question is not specific to the language, but my terminology is that `float` is 4 bytes and `double` is 8 bytes.

Comment: I would agree that double should be used unless you care about performance or POD size. I guess there was a time when people preferred 'short' over 'int' for the same reasons, but now less relevant.

Comment: I don't think it matter for performance for one-off uses, either.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074474/should-i-use-double-or-float

Answer (score 1):

As I point out [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357807/392585), there are a few ways in which `float` can be faster than `double`, but in general unless you're sure that floating-point is the bottleneck, I would suggest to stick to `double`. It will also avoid problems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1839422/392585), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18377240/392585) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20855633/392585).

An obvious exception is if there is only hardware support is for single precision (such as [Cortex M4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M)).

Comment: Even if there is a strong performance argument, it only means the analysis should be done to see if float is good enough. There is no point getting wrong answers fast.